# Jquery remove class and replace by a new one

Tags: jquery, removeclass

When i click on a button, i want to remove a class and replace with by other one.
I have the following html content :

```
<div class="mainDiv-34">
   <div class="row one red"></div>
   <div class="row two red"></div>
   <div class="row three red"></div>
 </div>
```

What i want to do is to replace the `class="row two red"` by `class="row two green"`,  but the **row two green** is addded next to my mainDiv-34 instead ! Why ?

Here's my JS :

```
$('.mainDiv-34').removeClass("row two red").addClass("row two green");
```

Comment: You are targeting the parent and not the child

Comment: `row two red` is not _one_ class here, it is _three_ classes. Removing the first two, only to then add them again, is nonsense. Just remove `red`, and add `green`.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.mainDiv-34')` means that you are selecting the top level div.

You need to do something like this instead:

```
$('.row.one.red').removeClass("row one red").addClass("row one green");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting the right div.

```
$('.mainDiv-34 div.row.two.red').removeClass("row two red").addClass("row two green");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.mainDiv-34').find('div.two').removeClass("red").addClass("green");
```

Comment: Do ensure you add an explanation rather than just leaving a chunk of code.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are removing/adding the classes to the parent div, try

```
$(".mainDiv-34").find(".row.two").removeClass("red").addClass("green")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector points to the parent div `.mainDiv-34`. You need to target its child elements.

**Scenario 1** : Change the class on a specific element inside `.mainDiv-34`.

```
$('.mainDiv-34 div.row.two').removeClass('red').addClass('green');
```

**Scenario 2** : Change the class on all elements inside `.mainDiv-34` with class `row`.

```
 $('.mainDiv-34 div.row').removeClass('red').addClass('green');
```

**Scenario 3** : toggle class on a all elements inside `.mainDiv-34` with class `row`.

```
$('.mainDiv-34 div.row').click(function()
{
  $(this).toggleClass('red green');
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/r3yuyapk/